# Load a resource in executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm facing a problem of folder with an executable jar.

In fact I want to call

```
    URL keystoreURL = ServerGUI.class.getResource("/resources/keystore");
    String keystorePath = keystoreURL.getPath();
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keystorePath);
```

to load a keyStore.
Because setProperty wants a String to access the file.

My resources folder is inside the /src folder of Eclipse. 
Everything works when working inside Eclipse but if I want to create an executable jar file, the Path is not correct even if the resources folder also exists.

edit: Another interesting thing when printing the path :
In Eclipse: file:/C:/Users/Xenom/workspace/eBankingRMI/bin/resources/truststore

In jar : jar:file:/C:/Users/Xenom/Desktop/ClientBanking.jar!/resources/truststore

So clearly setProperty can't read the second one...

Comment: I *suspect* that the API is looking to a `File` and not a `URL` reference

Comment: In fact the best would be to give a relative path like /resources/keystore but if I write this directly in setProperty I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: \resources\keystore (The system cannot find the path specified) ..

Comment: unzip the jar that is created and look at the internal folder structure

Comment: The structure is okay, it's just that the string path is not correct as you can see in my edit.

Comment: I *suspect* that the API that is trying to load the keystore is trying to do so through a `File` reference, and `new File("jar:file:/C:/Users/Xenom/Desktop/ClientBanking.jar!/resources/truststore")` is not a valid file.  Also, your original post says `/resources/keystore` but your update says `/resources/truststore`

Comment: Yeah sorry actually the problem is the same with the keystore and the truststore but even if he wants a File reference how can I do to make it work both for Eclipse and a jar file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that a resource URL matches an actual file system file. It won't be the case in a jar or a war most of the time.

If your API absolutely require a file (and AFAIK keystore does), you'll need to grab that URL and stream it to an actual filesystem file, and then use that to set the property.